# gl.h - how to hide function prototypes

Tags: c, linux, opengl

I work on Linux. In  have a legacy OpenGL application which includes gl.h. I would like to define a function pointer for storing glXGetProcAddress result:

```
typedef void (GLACTIVETEXTUREARB)(GLenum texture);
extern GLACTIVETEXTUREARB glActiveTextureARB;
```

but I get the following error: *redefinition of glActiveTextureARB as different kind of symbol, previous definition: gl.h:1966*

I have to include gl.h because it contains basic types definitions, for example GLenum. How to hide that function prototype ? glext.h defines function prototypes based on GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES but gl.h doesn't use it.

Comment: Don't know if it is applicable to this specific problem, but you may also try defining `GL_GLEXT_LEGACY` and `GLX_GLXEXT_LEGACY` macros to avoid Linux headers unintentional include of system-provided `glext.h`

Comment: GL_GLEXT_LEGACY is not applicable here

Comment: if this is for C++ how about using namespace ?

Comment: C,  it's pity that a system gl.h doesn't offer option like GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a define to rewrite the original name:

```c
#define glActiveTextureARB glh__glActiveTextureARB
#include<gl.h>
#undef glActiveTextureARB
```

By the way, your `gl.h` probably already has `PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREARBPROC` defined as the function pointer type you want to have, so you don't need to redefine it.